# How to initialize Iterable<Map.Entry<String, String>> in Spring XML configuration?

Tags: xml, spring, atlassian-crowd

I would like to initialize a bean having the following property:

```
private Iterable<Map.Entry<String, String>> groupToAuthorityMappings;
```

In my context.xml, I expected to do it this way:

```
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd"
         default-autowire="byName">

    <beans:bean id="crowdUserDetailsService"
        class="com.atlassian.crowd.integration.springsecurity.user.CrowdUserDetailsServiceImpl">
        ...
        <beans:property name="groupToAuthorityMappings">
            <beans:map>
                <beans:entry key="Manager" value="ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR,ROLE_USER"/>
            </beans:map>
        </beans:property>
        ...
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

But I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.util.LinkedHashMap] to required type [java.lang.Iterable] for property 'groupToAuthorityMappings': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

I cannot change the bean since it comes from a provided library.
Does anybody know how I can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're defining this data as a `Map`, you can use a `factory-method` to get an iterator over the entries:

```
<util:map id='groupToAuthority>
    <beans:entry key="some-group" value="specific-authority-for-group" />
    ...
</util:map>

<bean class='ClassRequiringAnIterable'>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean factory-bean='groupToAuthority' factory-method='entrySet'/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

However, note that you require an `Iterable<Map.Entry<String, String>>`, and your sample defines a `Map<String, List<String>>`, so make sure that each group is mapped to exactly one role.

Comment: Indeed, my map cannot works this way. I will update my question. I tried your code, but I cannot create beans:map as a direct child of beans:beans. How to declare it?

Comment: Ok, I successfully solved my issue:
1) Add http://www.springframework.org/schema/util and http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd in xsi:schemaLocation
2) Add xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" in beans:beans
3) Use <util:map> instead of <beans:map> as suggested in your answer
4) contructor-arg does not fit for the property, I used instead:
        <beans:property name="groupToAuthorityMappings">
            <beans:bean factory-bean="groupToAuthorityMap" factory-method="entrySet"></beans:bean>
        </beans:property>

Answer (score 0):

Rather than mess around with trying to create iterables in spring xml, I would use this approach. Create a factory for the bean:

```
public class ThirdPartyBeanFactory {

    public ThirdPartyBean getInstance(Map<String,String> map) {
        ThirdPartyBean tpb = new ThirdPartyBean(); //This is the provided object you cant change
        tpb.setGroupToAuthorityMappings(map.entrySet());
        return tpb;
    }
}
```

Then in XML
First create instance of the factory (thirdPartyBeanFactory) and map (mapBean).Then define your bean like so:

```
<bean id="thirdPartyBean" factory-bean="thirdPartyBeanFactory"
        factory-method="getInstance">
    <constructor-arg ref="mapBean" />
</bean>
```